# Applying shifting counting efficiently to a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

I am performing an operation on each column of a `DataFrame` *which is indexed by weeks*. Namely, in each column, I count the first occurence in which an entry does not equal the previous entry (not including the first entry), and output the difference between the last time period and the period in which this occured.

The problem is that this is very slow and I am not sure how to streamline it, potentially using `numpy`. Here is my code:

```
def sh(ser):
    if ser.drop_duplicates().shape[0]==1:
        return np.nan
    s = ( ser!=ser.shift() )[1:]
    a=s[s].index[0]
    b=s.index[-1]
    c = - (a-b)
    return c.days/7 + 1

cols = prices.columns
timeDiffs = []
for col in cols:
    ser = prices[col]
    timeDiffs.append(sh(ser))
output = pd.Series(timeDiffs)
```

To get an idea of what this does, if `df is the following:

```
               0      1      2
index                                   
2015-11-15     9      15.0   8
2015-11-22     9      15.0   8
2015-11-28     3.2    15.0   8
2015-12-06     3.2    15.0   8
2015-12-13     4      15.0   8
2015-12-20     5      15.0   2
```

The `output` is:

```
4
nan
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index to datetime

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df_1 = df.diff(-1).fillna(method='ffill').astype(bool).cumsum().replace(0,np.nan)
(df_1.idxmax() - df_1.idxmin()).astype('timedelta64[D]') / 7

0    4.0
1    NaN
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives [3,nan,1], instead of [4,nan,1] for the above example

Comment: How is the first column equal to 4?

Comment: because that is how many observations are left in the column, starting from  (and including) the first period at which there was any change. Note the `return c.days/7 + 1` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
index = [u'2015-11-15', u'2015-11-22', u'2015-11-28', u'2015-12-06', u'2015-12-13', u'2015-12-20']
df = DataFrame({0: [9, 9, 3.2, 3.2, 4, 5], 1: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15], 2: [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2]}, index)
df.apply(lambda x: (x.diff().fillna(0) != 0).astype(int).sum())
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives [3,nan,1], instead of [4,nan,1] for the above example

Comment: Sorry! Pay not enouch attention to your code. 
How many rows are in DataFrame? 
And how much time your code execute?